# Reference to longtable wrong if \numberwithin{table}{section} is activated

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, longtable, tabu, chngcntr

I've encountered something weird while using the longtable package together with `\numberwithin{table}{section}` or `\counterwithin{table}{section}`: if a longtable is the first table in a section, it will not be referenced correctly (with `\ref{}`); instead the reference will point to the last first-in-a-section longtable in the document. Note that the error is carried forward to other packages which rely on longtable such as tabu (longtabu).

While searching for a solution, I found duplicate entries for the first-in-a-section longtables in the aux-file, which is why I am suspecting this to be a bug. However, my LaTeX knowledge is limited and I am happy to be proven wrong.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Reference to Table \ref{tab:Label1}\\
Reference to Table \ref{tab:Label2}\\

\clearpage
\section{}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{tab:Label1}\\
\toprule 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Header}}  \\
\midrule 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{footnotesize}\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}\end{footnotesize}} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Header}}  \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\begin{footnotesize}\textit{Continued on next page}\end{footnotesize}} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
some variable & some explaination\\
\midrule
some variable & some explaination \\
\end{longtable}

\clearpage
\section{}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
\caption{Caption.}
\label{tab:Label2}\\
\toprule 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Header}}  \\
\midrule 
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{footnotesize}\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}\end{footnotesize}} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Header}}  \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{\begin{footnotesize}\textit{Continued on next page}\end{footnotesize}} \\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
some variable & some explanation\\
\midrule
some variable & some explanation \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

On my computer, both references point to the latter table.

- Do your computers replicate the error?
- Does anybody have an idea what could cause this error?
- Would anybody know a workaround?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Put the `\numberwithin` command *after* loading `hyperref`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, settings should be made *after* loading packages (there are some exceptions); this is a case: since `hyperref` modifies the macros that manage counters, your `\numberwithin` given before the package is loaded leads to the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\numberwithin{table}{section}
```